# High memory usage on iKImageBrowserView (or create memory quality thumbnail?)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ikimagebrowserview

In my mac application I'm currently developing, I have an `iKImageBrowserView` which displays something like 500/1000 Images.

*Turning off* image display, memory consumption is very low around 50 MB.
*Turning on* image display, memory consumption is very high around 500 MB.
Every time I scroll up/down, memory usage is increased.

Here is a snippet of `imageBrowser:itemAtIndex` :

```
    ..
    MyBrowserNSImageItem *item = [[MyBrowserNSImageItem alloc] initWithCover:coverImage andId:myFile];
    return [item autorelease];
```

where `coverImage` is read from an object cache and it is not initialized every time.

How could I decrease memory usage?

**Update**: I tried to use `imageVersion`: from DataSourceProtocol but still high memory usage. If I initializes images but don't pass them to ikImageBrowserView memory is low.

**Other Update**: I did another test. Every time I allocate an object of a simple PNG image.   And this time memory is low. Problem arises only when I use real images. They are JPG of around 50/100KB. Probably when they are loaded in memory they decompress. How can I reduce memory usage of an NSImage?

**Update**: Problem is in the quality of JPEG. They consume too much memory when displayed. So question is: HOW to generate memory/quality thumbnail in Cocoa?

Comment: dont load all the images at the same time you can do lazy loading..means only load images when you need them

Comment: How Can I detect when I need them? I have only this method (imageBrowser:itemAtIndex) that tells me to show an image

Comment: wat about using  CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex() this will give you the thumbnail of that image rather than loading whole image

Comment: I suspect the problem is not in the thumbnail (I have 500 small images ). The problem is that every time I scroll memory increases at large rate

Comment: You should probably cache the image items when you create them so that you're not creating new ones all the time.

Comment: Already done. Still same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the aim of sharing my experience for future readers I found my problem. It was a memory leak in my code. The leak was very trivial in my custom ImageBrowserItem.

As another optimization I switched from NSImage to NSData representation (it consumes less memory).

As a last optimization (that I am going to think) is about quality of thumbnails. I am thinking to show different thumb quality according zoom value. What do you think?

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same memory issues. Just out of curiosity, what was the leak issue in the ImageBrowserItem?